# Is there any way to get all database storedprocs used in a delphi form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Actually I want all database storedprocedures used in a delphi form. Can you please help me how I can get all these?

Actually am using Unidac with sybase. In our pretty old procedures, we are using "where col1 <> null" which is not acceptable with Unidac.

Now I have to change it to "where col1 is not null"

Please let me know is there any easy way to get all database storedprocedures used in Delphi form.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't it easier to look at the metadata of your database? Why are you looking for stored procedures on forms?

Comment: ok eg: StoredProcGetName(delphi SP) using get_name()..(sybse proc)..I want get_name() which are harcoded in StoredProcGetName.name

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for us was doing a simple search (regex if needed) on all files for specific keywords and filter out the false positives afterwards.

As search tool, I can highly recommend [Powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) but there are several free alternatives that would get you the results you need.